# How to create a link file with custom picture?

Tags: nautilus

While sharing some software it's a good idea to include a link file ( address launcher of home page). A file without an image is not eye catchable.
How to create a link file with a custom image as icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a application launcher. For this save the following to a file with `.desktop` extension. Make it executable (`chmod +x filename`)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=askubuntu.com
Type=Link
URL=http://www.askubuntu.com
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/firefox.png
```

change `/usr/share/pixmaps/firefox.png` to your icon, `http://www.askubuntu.com` to your link